# Conditional Density Function on Underlying Exponential

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, density-function, rao-blackwell

**Problem Statement:** Suppose $Y_1, Y_2,\dots, Y_n$ are a random sample from an exponential distribution with mean $\theta.$ Let $\displaystyle U=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i.$ Find the conditional density function for $Y_1$ given $U:\; f_{Y_1|U}(y_1|u).$

Note: This is essentially Exercise 9.86**b** in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer. The problem is posed in the context of $U$ as a sufficient statistic, and of using the Rao-Blackwell Theorem to find the MVUE of $e^{-t/\theta}.$

**My Work So Far:** The conditional density function is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{Y_1|U}(y_1|u)
&=\frac{f(y_1,u)}{f_U(u)}.
\end{align*}
Now the density function for $Y_1$ is given by
$$f_1(y_1)=\frac{1}{\theta}\,e^{-y_1/\theta},$$
and the sum function $U=\sum Y_i$ would then have, by virtue of the mgf,
\begin{align*}
m_U(t)
&=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\theta t)^{-1}\\
&=(1-\theta t)^{-n},
\end{align*}
which is the mgf for a Gamma distribution with parameters
$\beta=\theta$ and $\alpha=n.$ It
follows that
$$f_U(u)=\frac{u^{n-1}\,e^{-u/\theta}}{\Gamma(n)\,\theta^n}.$$
Now $u=y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_n,$ so that $y_1=u-y_2-y_3-\cdots-y_n.$
By the logic we have already used, if we let $S=\sum_{i=2}^nY_i,$ then
the distribution function for $S$ is a Gamma with parameters
$\beta=\theta$ and $\alpha=n-1.$ Also, $u=y_1+s,$ or
$y_1=u-s.$ Note that $y_1$ and $s$ are independent. It follows that
\begin{align*}
f_{(Y_1,S)}(y_1,s)
&=f_{Y_1}(y_1)\,f_S(s)\\
&=\frac1\theta\,e^{-y_1/\theta}\,
 \frac{s^{n-2}\,e^{-s/\theta}}{\Gamma(n-1)\,\theta^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{s^{n-2}\,e^{-(y_1+s)/\theta}}{\Gamma(n-1)\,\theta^n}.
\end{align*}

**My Question:** I think I'm on the right track, but I also think I'm missing something fairly straight-forward. How do I push through to get the desired conditional probability density function?

I have examined a few questions, especially [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172215/find-the-joint-distribution-of-x-1-and-sum-i-1n-x-i). I do not understand the method of solution there, and the notation they are using is confusing: are they working with $U$ or $Y_n?$ [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298138/mvue-using-factorization-criterion-and-rao-blackwell-theorems) is taking a different approach (doing the expectation without knowing the distribution function), and so doesn't help me.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252692/, which poses the same exercise, presents a different kind of solution.  I'm not voting to close, though, because you are really asking about your particular *method* with an aim to addressing a related problem.  You still might find some of the ideas used there--especially concerning the exchangeability of the $Y_i$--will be helpful in general.